# Uso de OneHotEncoder

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

Tengo que pasar mi categoria 'property_type' a valor numérico. Lo realiza a través de OneHotEncoder. Pero en mi variable PH me figura NaN como si fuese un valor faltante, los cuales ya complete. Ademas, me figura como 0 1 y 2 y no como categoría Departamento, Casa o PH que son mis variables categóricas. Adjunto el código. Gracias[image: las variables a las que me transformo son las columnas 0 1 y 2]

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: Me figura en las ultimas filas correspondiente a PH como valor faltante y no como un numero. No se porque me sucede eso